# TFS/ MSBuild Add ChangeSet Number to Web.Config

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

Does anyone know of a good solution for adding the changeset number of a build (in TFS 2012) to the web.config of a web site being built?

We don't want it as part of the assembly version, but as a completely separate entry.

Thanks,

Kieron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add a Custom Workflow Activity to the build process template to do this.

Ewald Hofman has a great [blog series](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) on how to do this. Part 5 has a tutorial on editing the Assembly Version, you can use this as a template but instead edit your web.config.

You should find the Changeset Id in: the `BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion` property.

**N.B.** as this is TFS 2012, you will probably have Local Workspaces on by default, so you don't need to fiddle the Read Only flags on files.